# How do i add an horizontal line using html and css in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css

I want to add a small horizontal line like the one on the [page](https://prnt.sc/iBhHsJF5zD0Y).
I tried using the `<hr\>` tag but i don't get the desired line, is there any other way to add this line.
The code below describes what i've done so far to construct the line but i have not been able to achieve it.
Please could someone help me create the line
Thanks

```css
.second-bg-cover{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)) ,url(../img/state1.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .second-cover-heading {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 60px 0;
    color: var(--white);
  }

  .second-cover-photo-section h1{
    font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .second-cover-download{
    background: transparent;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    border-color: var(--white);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

  }
  .second-cover-download{
    margin-left:580px;
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="second-bg-cover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 second-cover-heading">
    <h1 class="text-center">STYLISH AXURE DESIGN</h1>
    <hr style="width:80px;height:2px;text-align:left;margin-left:660px;border: 1.5px solid white; color: white;">
    <p class="text-center mt-4">Use the selections you need, remove the lines you don't need.Create gorgeous prototypes faster than ever!
    </p>
    <div class="second-cover-download">
      <button class="second-cover-download ms-5" type="button">Download</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing style for `.footer::before`

Comment: sorry didn't understand....i didn't use any footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `::after` like this:

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="text-center with_underline">STYLISH AXURE DESIGN</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
.with_underline::after{
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  width: 120px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43e6r07m/

Comment: if i want to put it top of the image will i have to put z-index?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hr`tag to create a line, or create a class named "spacer" that will allow you to customize the line. For example :

```css
  .spacer{
            width:100%;
            border:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            margin:0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .myContainer{
            width:80%;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="myContainer">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
        <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
```